# Firestore getDoc() not saving on useState() hook in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a doc value from firebase using the getDoc() method. It's working. But can't save on useState() hook in ReactJS

Here is my code:

```
const [post, setPost] = React.useState(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPost = async () => {
            const docSnap = await getDoc(doc(db, "posts", id));
            setPost(docSnap.data())
        }

        return () => fetchPost();
    }, []);
```

Comment: Can you try calling `fetchPost()` and removing the `return...` line?

Comment: `return () => fetchPost();` This means you want the fetch to happen when the effect **is torn down**, not when the effect runs. Just call `fetchPost()`